# Symfony2 Bootstrap navbar Prod mode

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, symfony

I am a beginner in Symfony 
I am trying to use a bootstrap navbar in a simple Symfony project 
the problem is that it works in dev mode but in prod mode the menu "dropdown" is not shown when it is clicked .

This screenshot is taken in dev mode:
[image]

Comment: Clear the cache for prod.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's solved with this command : 
`php app/console assetic:dump --env=prod --no-debug`
thna clearing cache for prod

Answer (score 0):

Check to see if you're getting 404s errors in the console. If so you need to run both:

`php app/console assets:install; 
php app/console assetic:dump;`

The problem is that in your dev environment the assets are loaded through a controller. See here for more information: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/assetic/asset_management.html

Comment: are you seeing the errors i mention? how are you integrating bootstrap into symfony ?

Comment: I was following a tuto via youtube
I put CSS JS FONTS folders into Web folder

Comment: You need to put it in the Resources/public folder and then run the command. What tutorial were you following?

Comment: well, french is not my fort. Maybe if you update your answer with some screenshots from the browser console on prod mode I could help you more.