# Symfony2 Bootstrap3 navbar dropdown Prod mode

Tags: symfony, twitter-bootstrap-3, navbar, production-environment, assetic

I have the same problem as described here : [Symfony2 Bootstrap navbar Prod mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35102737/symfony2-bootstrap-navbar-prod-mode/40612430#40612430)

Bootstrap3 navbar dropdown buttons work in dev mode but not in prog mode (nothing happens when I click) even though I did `php app/console assetic:dump --env=prod --no-debug`

Let me know if you need more info !

---

Here is my .twig :

```
    {% stylesheets filter='cssrewrite, ?yui_css'
    'assets/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css'
    'assets/bootstrap/css/bootstrap-theme.css'
    'assets/css/design.css'
    'js/autocomplete/awesomplete.css' %}
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset_url }}" type="text/css" />
    {% endstylesheets %}

...

<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="menu-1">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">      
                    {% if app.user is not null and is_granted('ROLE_ADMIN') %}
                    <li><a title="Documentation" href="{{ asset('/doc/RAPPORT.pdf') }}">Documentation utilisateur</a></li>

                    <li class="dropdown">
                        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Universités<span class="caret"></span></a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            <li><a href="{{ path('Mb_univ_list') }}">Liste des universités partenaires</a></li>
                            <li><a href="{{ path('mb_places_list_admin') }}">Modifier/Ajouter des jetons/universités</a></li>
                            <li><a href="{{ path('Mb_univ_import') }}" >Ajouter plusieurs universités d'un coup</a></li>
                            {% block menu_universite %}
                            {% endblock %}
                        </ul>
                    </li>
```

---

Here is my config.yml :

```
# Assetic Configuration
assetic:
    debug:          "%kernel.debug%"
    use_controller: false
    bundles:        [ ]
    #java: /usr/bin/java
    filters:
        cssrewrite: ~
        yui_css:
            jar: "%kernel.root_dir%/Resources/java/yuicompressor.jar"
        yui_js:
            jar: "%kernel.root_dir%/Resources/java/yuicompressor.jar"
```

Comment: have you deleted your cache? 

php app/console cache:clear -e prod

Comment: Yes I have. Also, a '#' appear at the end of the url in prod mode.

Comment: I might be wrong but it feels to me like a path problem with your javascript. If the interface is right, it means your CSS is loaded properly. If nothing happens when you press a dropdown item (which is driven by JS), it can mean 2 things: 1st: path to your bootstrap JS might be wrong in production (but good in dev), 2nd, there may be a javascript error that makes the whole JS crashes.